# The last column is ignored or not created by SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have a serious problem with SQLite in android studio!!
Actually , i have  created a table with some columns,but in execution of an insert method the logcat return an error informing that the last column"i named hours" dosen't exist in the table!!!

the logcat error:
  [Logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lboyd.jpg)

The code for creating the table and the database in DataBaseHelper.java:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

static final String Tag="MyActivite";
public static final String DataBaseName="Bus";
public static final String TABLE_Name="LigneDestination";
public static final String Col_2="ligne";
public static final String Col_3="gareDéparts";
public static final String Col_4="destination";
public static final String Col_5="hours";

public static final String Table_Creation="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_Name+"                     
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, " +
""+Col_2+" INTEGER, " +Col_3+ " TEXT, "+Col_4+" TEXT, 
"+Col_5+"TEXT);";


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DataBaseName, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL(Table_Creation);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
db.execSQL("Drop TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_Name);
onCreate(db);
}


boolean insertData(int ligne ,String gare_depart,String destination 
,String hours ){



SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values =new ContentValues();

values.put(Col_2,ligne);
values.put(Col_3,gare_depart);
values.put(Col_4,destination);
values.put(Col_5,hours);
long result=db.insert(TABLE_Name,null,values);

if(result==-1){
Log.e(Tag,"l'insertion est échoué");
return false;}
else {
Log.i(Tag,"l'insertion est réussi");
return true;
}

}}
```

Could you help me please !

Comment: You might want to include the code for creating and inserting to the table. And never post code or error messages as images. They’re text, include them as such and format them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to a space being omitted between the column name and the column type. Thus a column name **hoursTEXT** will be created not **hours** and hence why the hours column is not found.

To fix :-

- 1 Change `public static final String Table_Creation="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_Name+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, " +""+Col_2+" INTEGER, " +Col_3+ " TEXT, "+Col_4+" TEXT,"+Col_5+"TEXT);";` to `public static final String Table_Creation="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_Name+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, " +Col_2+" INTEGER, " +Col_3+ " TEXT, "+Col_4+" TEXT,"+Col_5+" TEXT);";` i.e. add a space before TEXT for Col_5 (also removes useless +""+ between id column definition and Col_2 definition).
- 2 do **one** of the following :-

  - Delete the App's data.
  - Uninstall the App.
  - Increase the database version from 1 to 2 i.e.

    - Change `super(context, DataBaseName, null, 1);` to `super(context, DataBaseName, null, 2);`
- 3 Rerun the App.

Comment: Thank you Mr this was a details, that cause me 1 day looping in void!

Comment: @AhmedHaddad, if this fixed your issue then please mark answer as correct.